# Are multiple polygons possible?

Tags: css, polygon, css-shapes, clip-path

I'm trying to create a pyramid. I figured I'd use the CSS `clip-path` for that. I meant to do a triangle (which I managed to do) and several trapezoids beneath it (even the first one failed).

```css
.container {
  min-width: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
}

.triangle {
  background-color: yellow;
  clip-path: polygon(90% 100%, 50% 0%, 10% 100%);
}

.trapeze {
  background-color: blue;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 10%, 0% 90%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
}

div {
  min-height: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="triangle"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <dic class="trapeze"> </dic>
</div>
```

Finally, here's the result :

[image]

I'm not working with any framework and I am using Firefox 67

Comment: If your html is what you actually have, then note that your trapeze div element is misnamed as dic

Comment: That's FAR better. However, my trapezoid is still not a trapezoid. Thanks.

Comment: Your clip-path ordering might need changing. Looking at https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/ and selecting the Trapezoid example, it suggests your clip path should be something like 10% 0%, 90% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `clip-path` once then rely on gradient to simulate the different shapes:

```css
.pyramid {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  
  -webkit-clip-path:polygon(0 100%,100% 100%, 50% 0);
  clip-path:polygon(0 100%,100% 100%, 50% 0);
  background:
    linear-gradient(to bottom,
      yellow 0    20%,
      red    20%  50%,
      blue   50% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="pyramid">

</div>
```

Comment: That's actually far better than what I've come up with. Thanks