# Render JSX-elements as multi-level pyramid

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I need to create a pyramid figure with 4 levels division something like this:
[image]

Although I have achieved the same with the following code set:

```js
const PyramidChart = () => {
  return (
    <div className="d-flex flex-column align-items-center pyramid_wrap">
      <div className="category_one">
        <h6>2</h6>
      </div>
      <div className="category_two">
        <h6>8</h6>
      </div>
      <div className="category_three">
        <h6>11</h6>
      </div>
      <div className="category_four">
        <h6>16</h6>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <PyramidChart />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
.pyramid_wrap {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.category_one {
  width: 70px;
  height: 30px;
  border-left: 35px solid transparent;
  border-right: 35px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 50px solid tomato;
}

.category_two {
  width: 116px;
  height: 30px;
  border-left: 22px solid transparent;
  border-right: 22px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 28px solid orange;
}

.category_three {
  width: 162px;
  height: 30px;
  border-left: 22px solid transparent;
  border-right: 22px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 28px solid cyan;
}

.category_four {
  width: 208px;
  height: 30px;
  border-left: 22px solid transparent;
  border-right: 22px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 28px solid teal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

And got something like this:

[image]

But the issue I am unable to resolve is to align the text in top-level pyramid area to center. It is somehow always out of sync with the  it is aligned in.

Any help to rectify this issue is appreciated :)

Comment: You can actually use `<span>` tag instead of `<h1>` and then apply css to the span tag. `<h1>`. Also `<span>` is an inline element.

Comment: How is this html and css only if you are using reactjs? :)

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56539403/8620333

Comment: @bubble-cord : stacking individual CSS settings for each and every new layer may become tedious, I would rather recommend to delegate that part to React and solve the issue in [a bit more flexible way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62531468/11299053)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the possible solutions is to use [CSS mask](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-image) over the entire pyramid's wrapper. It may be not well supported as of now, yet provides genuine way of shaping your pyramid with SVG path (triangle):

[image]

In order not to let the mask shrink (hiding upper and lower layers), you may need to preserve the `min-width` of a wrapper (equal to number of layers multiplied by layer height - `3em`).

To avoid layer labels falling outside of the mask, you may need to center the mask according to labels position (`mask-position: center`)

Live-demo, implementing that concept, might look as follows:

```js
const { render } = ReactDOM,
      rootNode = document.getElementById('root')

const pyramidItems = [{label:'2', color: '#f47660'}, {label:'8', color:'#fcae60'}, {label:'11', color:'#a7e6db'}, {label:'16',color:'#79d4c5'}]

const Pyramid = ({items}) => (
  <div 
    className="wrapper"
    style={{minWidth:`${items.length}*3em`}}
  >
    {
      items.map(({label,color},key) => (
        <div 
          key={key}
          className="layer"
          style={{backgroundColor:color}}
        >
          {label}
        </div>
      ))
    }
  </div>
)

render (
  <Pyramid items={pyramidItems} />,
  rootNode
)
```

```css
.wrapper {
  --triangle-shape: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMTAwIDEwMCIgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIj48cGF0aCBkPSJNNTAsMCBMMTAwLDEwMCBMMCwxMDAgeiIvPjwvc3ZnPg==");
  -webkit-mask-image: var(--triangle-shape);
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask-position: center;
  mask-image: var(--triangle-shape);
  mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  mask-position: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.layer {
  height: 3em;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: .2em solid #fff;
  margin: -.2em 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: That's really quite a dynamic solution. Thanks a lot. But one doubt though, When I try to increase the width, it doe not seems to work. Also the tip of top level is not pointed. Can you help out with these two?

Comment: If you can help me provide the actual svg image?

Comment: I am open to the solutions that suits best since each of the solution is a good learning experience for me. After you posted your question, I used that since it seems more dynamically more feasible to me because I need to render the synamic data in it soon

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216562/discussion-between-bubble-cord-and-yevgen-gorbunkov).

Comment: Yes I am unable to resize the width of the pyramid properly.

Comment: Can you continue in a chat link above?

Comment: @bubble-cord : as labels are centered, in order to keep them visible (fall inside the mask polygon), you may do `mask-position: center` and preserve `min-width` of a wrapper not to let your mask shape shrink hiding outer layers of the pyramid. Check out [this fix](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ucsvwu)

Answer (score 4):

Let's try moving from CSS Triangle to `:before` and `:after` with `skew` transform property.

I haven't changed your HTML, just add a `.value` class to your `<h6>` to style them.

Basically all you have to do is to set to every `<div>` a `:before` with a negative degree angle and a `:after` with a positive degree angle and give them the same background color, in order to match.

Only for the top-level `<div>` I used a CSS Triangle, so you already know how it works.

In order to make the values horizontally and vertically aligned I used flexbox on the parent, combined with `justify-content: center;` (horizontal align) and `align-items: center;` (vertical align). Don't forget to always add a `line-height:1em;` and remove margin to the element you want to be vertical aligned. If the `line-height` is not equal to its actual height it will always be some pixels up or down the middle axe.

```css
.pyramid_wrap {
  margin-top: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.category_one,
.category_two,
.category_three,
.category_four {
  position: relative;
  margin: 6px auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.category_one:before,
.category_one:after,
.category_two:before,
.category_two:after,
.category_three:before,
.category_three:after,
.category_four:before,
.category_four:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 100%;
  content: "";
}

.category_one:before,
.category_two:before,
.category_three:before,
.category_four:before {
  left: -15px;
  transform: skew(-25deg);
}

.category_one:after,
.category_two:after,
.category_three:after,
.category_four:after {
  right: -15px;
  transform: skew(25deg);
}

.category_one {
    width: 20px;
    height: 40px;
    background: tomato;

}

.category_one:before,
.category_one:after {
  width: 30px;
  height: 40px;
  background: tomato;
}

.category_one:before {
  left: -16px;
  top: 0;
}
.category_one:after {
  right: -16px;
  top: 0;
}

.category_one .value:after {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: -55px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 28px 70px 28px;
  border-color: transparent transparent tomato transparent;
}


.category_two {
    width: 70px;
    height: 40px;
    background: orange;
}

.category_two:before,
.category_two:after {
  width: 40px;
  background: orange;
}

.category_two:before {
  left: -12px;
}
.category_two:after {
  right: -12px;
}


.category_three {
  width: 120px;
  height: 40px;
  background: cyan;
}

.category_three:before,
.category_three:after {
  background: cyan;
}
.category_three:before {
  left: -9px;
}
.category_three:after {
  right: -9px;
}


.category_four {
    width: 150px;
    height: 40px;
    background: teal;
}

.category_four:before,
.category_four:after {
  background: teal;
}

.value {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1em;
}
```

```html
 <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center pyramid_wrap">
        <div class="category_one">
            <h6 class="value">2</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="category_two">
          <h6 class="value">8</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="category_three">
          <h6 class="value">11</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="category_four">
          <h6 class="value">16</h6>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: One more question though, what is the use of defining classes with and without :after, :before together?

Comment: when I group together for example .category_one,.category_two,.category_three,.category_four { /* ... */ } it's because they share the same style and the style will be applied to the div itself, when I group for example .category_one:before,.category_two:before,.category_three:before,.category_four:before {transform: skew(-25deg);} it's because I know all the left sides (:before) will have a negative degree angle. It's just that you don't repeat transform: skew(-25deg); everytime. For more info about pseudo-elements read here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp

Comment: Not this I am asking. .category_two {
  width: 70px;
  height: 40px;
  background: orange;
}

.category_two:before,
.category_two:after {
  width: 40px;
  background: orange;
}   This I am confused with

Comment: Ok I get why you get confused. I created a Codepen for you: https://codepen.io/alezuc/pen/MWKmJNp?editors=1100 here you can see on the .category_two the element itself is orange and the before with a background: blue; and a negative skew and the after with a background: green; and a positive skew. So the before and after need to be styled separately. Anyways tries always to inspect element pressing F12 on your keyboard, so you can visualize all the elements on your page with their style. I hope to have clear your doubts, otherwise, let me know!

Comment: Oh okay. So the blue and green are the default colors provided with psuedo elements, so we are over-riding them with the colour of our choice

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216480/discussion-between-alessio-and-bubble-cord).

Comment: No, a pseudo element has no style applied by default by the browser. I choose green and blue only to make them more visibile to you. I really suggest you to read some articles for example: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/ I'm sure things will get clearer after reading it :)

Comment: Okay. I will go through them. Thanks for such detailed help :)

Comment: Glad to help! My suggestion is to learn how to use pseudo-elements because they are very powerful and flexible!